# Calling 'destroy' on dropdownchecklist not working in jQuery 2.1.3

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

```
$("#myDropdown").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
$("#myDropdown").dropdownchecklist({ icon: {}, emptyText: "Select GatePass Type", forceMultiple: false, closeRadioOnClick: true, maxDropHeight: 250, width: 200 });
```

I have the above jquery code, it works with out error in jQuery 1.7.2 but throws below error in jQuery 2.1.3.

> Error: cannot call methods on dropdownchecklist prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

I have tried below modification, basically trying to check if it is initialized (not sure if that is right way of checking if it is initialized) but i still get the same error!

```
if ($("#myDropdown").initialized) {
$("#myDropdown").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

jQueryUI widgets (and plugins using the widget factory) normally have a `.data` property that can be used to detect whether the widget has been initialised or not:

```
if ($("#myDropdown").data("ui-dropdownchecklist")) {
    $("#myDropdown").dropdownchecklist("destroy");
}
```

Here's an example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/unhz22wy/

Also, keep in mind that [the plugin's page](http://dropdownchecklist.sourceforge.net/) says it's supposed to be used with jQuery 1.11, so you shouldn't be too surprised if you have compatibility issues with it